# POST var on PHP

Tags: php

If this is the vam dump of Request (var_dump($_REQUEST);):

```
array(1) {
  ["gift_edit"]=>
  array(11) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "IBM da colezionista"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["validbegin"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["day"]=>
      string(2) "31"
      ["month"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2013"
    }
    ["validend"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["day"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["month"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2015"
    }
    ["redemption"]=>
    string(13) "1234567888844"
    ["points"]=>
    string(4) "1200"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "6000"
    ["discount"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["codelist"]=>
    string(33) "unoperibm
dueperibm
treperibm
"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["_token"]=>
    string(40) "f2389c3d302630a624c10660aac218d279953d06"
  }
}
```

How do you retrieve **codelist**?

Answer (score 4):

`$_REQUEST['gift_edit']['codelist']` or `$_POST['gift_edit']['codelist']`.

Comment: +1 it's generally better to be explicit about the request method, and use `$_POST` or `$_GET` than `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @SDC Sorry to bump this, just wanted to say I agree, I was just aiming to keep the code as close to his.

Answer (score 1):

You could access it with the following code.

```
$_REQUEST['gift_edit']['codelist']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$test = $_REQUEST['gift_edit']['codelist'];
```